# Using a variable in a function call

Tags: function, variables, asp-classic

I have tried everything I can think of and to me, there's no reason for this not to work.  However, ASP is not my native language and I need some insight.  I have a variable that will be defined by a request from the URL.  I want to then use that variable in a function call.

```
if pub_id <> "" then
    response.write(pub_id)
    response.write(pulldownQuery("newsletter_publication",pub_id,"live",newsletter_query))
  else
    response.write(pulldownQuery("newsletter_publication","","live",newsletter_query))
  end if
```

However, that does not work.  What does work, though, is if I hard code an id into the value portion of the function call.

```
response.write(pulldownQuery("newsletter_publication",58,"live",newsletter_query))
```

When I print pub_id it returns 58 (or whatever the id happens to be).  What am I missing here that is causing my variable to not work with this function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution I found was to explicitly define my pub_id variable as an integer, not a string.

```
pub_id = CInt(pub_id)
```

Once I defined it as such, everythig worked like a charm.

Comment: I think if you post a portion of the `pulldownQuery` function (edit your question), it might help to explain _why_ explicitly converting `pub_id` to integer fixes the issue.  Then this question and answer can be more useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see whether your variable `pub_id` has a value already? You can take a look at this ASP Querystring exercise. http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_querystring.asp